# Modulo 10 for large Numbers | Checking if a number is in powers of 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, modulo

I want to check in Python if a (large integer) value is in powers of 10. Normally I would simply check the modulo 10 of the value. This works fine for values of up to 1.E+22, after that, it returns weird values:

```
lowInteger = 1.E12
highInteger = 1.E23

print(lowInteger % 10)      #as expected returns 0
>>> 0.0

print(highInteger % 10)     #returns 2.0 instead of 0.0, 1.E23 returns 3.0, etc
>>> 2.0
```

Comment: You created floats instead of integers.

Answer (score 5):

The floating point number `1.E23` is *not* a power of 10. It is the nearest representable number to the power of 10 you wanted. Its actual value is

```
>>> int(1e23)
99999999999999991611392
```

If you want exact integers, use ints, not floats. You want `10**23`.

```
>>> 10**23
100000000000000000000000
```

Also, if you want to check whether a number is a *power* of 10, `x % 10 == 0` is the wrong check anyway, because that's checking whether the number is a *multiple* of 10.

Comment: That solves it thanks. But I thought I read that in python, floating point values are not restricted as they are in for example C/C++, is that a misconception?

Comment: @Torilla: I don't know where you think you read that, but it's not true. Python `float` is basically just a wrapper around C `double`.

Comment: Python *ints* don't have the limitations of C integer types.